# Centering a Carousel Modal

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I created a carousel modal for Bootstrap and can't figure out how to properly center it regardless of screensize or if for example a mobilescreen is tilted vertically.

The CSS Code I have right now properly spaces the modal on a normal pc screen, but it doesnt work on mobile screen and the MOdal appears on the top of the screen instead of appearing in the middle as it should. neither

```
position
```

nor 
    vertical-alignment
worked for me.

```css
.modal {
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-left: 5%;
  padding-left: 5%;
  padding-top: 1%;
  text-align: middle;
  max-height: 90vh;
  max-width: 95vw;
}

.modal .carousel-inner {
  max-height: 100% ! important;
  position: center;
  text-align: middle;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.modal .carousel .item @media (max-width: 991px) {
  .modal {
    padding-top: 55%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Page Content -->
<div class="container">

  <h1 class="my-4 text-center text-lg-left" style="padding-bottom:3%;padding-left:0%">Gallerie</h1>
  <div class="row text-center text-lg-left">

    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6">
      <a href="#" class="d-block mb-4 h-100">
        <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Gallerie">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6">
      <a href="#" class="d-block mb-4 h-100">
        <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6">
      <a href="#" class="d-block mb-4 h-100">
        <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6">
      <a href="#" class="d-block mb-4 h-100">
        <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6">
      <a href="#" class="d-block mb-4 h-100">
        <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6">
      <a href="#" class="d-block mb-4 h-100">
        <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6">
      <a href="#" class="d-block mb-4 h-100">
        <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6">
      <a href="#" class="d-block mb-4 h-100">
        <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6">
      <a href="#" class="d-block mb-4 h-100">
        <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6">
      <a href="#" class="d-block mb-4 h-100">
        <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6">
      <a href="#" class="d-block mb-4 h-100">
        <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6">
      <a href="#" class="d-block mb-4 h-100">
        <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal" id="Gallerie">
    <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="First slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="Second slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="Third slide">
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!--/Gallerie-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The modal needs the proper structure as detailed the [Bootstrap 4 docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#vertically-centered). Just use **`modal-dialog-centered`** and you don't need the extra CSS...

https://www.codeply.com/go/BDNba719xE

```
<div class="modal" id="Gallerie">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                        <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="First slide">
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="Second slide">
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="Third slide">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This answered my question perfectly